# Java updating method parameter - will it loose scope?

Tags: java

If I update a method parameter to a new object will this be available for the entirety of the JVM life?

For example:

```
Class 1:

Pojo p = new Pojo("A");

class2.method2(p)

Class 2:

public void method2(Pojo p) {
  p = new Pojo("B");
}
```

I know this is a bit of a silly example and the new object should be returned instead of updated like this but curious to know what the behavior will be in terms of scopes / garbage collection.

Comment: Reassigning a variable inside a method doesn't affect the variable passed into the method. Java is passing pointers by value.

Comment: Does this also apply if I did p.setValue("b") ?

Comment: No, it doesn't.